# Using PHP CURL to download a file

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to download a .exe file using PHP CURL from the web server to the PC, using CURL to make the webserver login automatic. The problem I'm having is that the file is being written to the browser window instead of asking the user to save or run the file. I'm using the code below, how can I fix this to make it work like I want?

```
$username = "myuser";
$password = "mypassword";
$url="http://www.mywebsite.com/files/softwaredownload/myfile.exe";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should set the headers so the browser knows it has to display the save dialog.

`Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=<file name.ext>`

Also, bear in mind that `Content-Type` header should be before `Content-Disposition`.

Comment: Thank you, adding the Content-Disposition header worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Add to your code these lines:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
```

... and replace `curl_exec($ch)` with `$response = curl_exec($ch);`, so $response content might be saved into a local file with `file_put_contents()` of `fwrite()` methods.